# How to force the 3D extrusion to accept changes to the smart object?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d, smartobject

I have a simple smart object which was converted to 3D by extrusion. I edited the underlying smart object with `Edit Source` and saved it. However, the 3D "version" does not represent those changes - how can I make sure they get carried over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `Edit Source` you have to go the 3D Window -> XXX Front Material -> Properties -> Weird Icon next to "Base Color" -> Edit Texture -> Right-click on the Smart Object Layer -> Edit Contents and now you can change stuff, save it and they will be reflected in the 3D version.